# uwsgi giving permission denied error even when I set chmod-socket to 664: works on one machine but not the other

Tags: sockets, nginx, uwsgi

This is my `mysite_uwsgi.ini` file:

```
# mysite_uwsgi.ini file
[uwsgi]

# Django-related settings
# the base directory (full path)
chdir           = /home/user/Documents/CMS
# Django's wsgi file
module          = CMS.wsgi
# the virtualenv (full path)
home            = /home/user/.virtualenvs/CMS

# process-related settings
# master
master          = true
# maximum number of worker processes
processes       = 10
# the socket (use the full path to be safe
socket          = /home/user/Documents/mysite/mysite.sock

# ... with appropriate permissions - may be needed
chmod-socket    = 664

# clear environment on exit
vacuum          = true
```

and this is my `mysite_nginx.conf` file:

```
# mysite_nginx.conf

# the upstream component nginx needs to connect to
upstream django {
    server unix:///home/user/Documents/mysite/mysite.sock; # for a file socket
    # server 127.0.0.1:8001; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

# configuration of the server
server {
    # the port your site will be served on
    listen      8000;
    # the domain name it will serve for
    server_name 192.168.174.169; # substitute your machine's IP address or FQDN
    charset     utf-8;

    # max upload size
    client_max_body_size 75M;   # adjust to taste

    # Django media
    location /media  {
        alias /home/user/Documents/media;  # your Django project's media files - amend as required
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/user/Documents/mysite/mysiteapp/static; # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    }

    # Finally, send all non-media requests to the Django server.
    location / {
        uwsgi_pass  django;
        include     /home/user/Documents/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

Now when I run this:

```
uwsgi --ini mysite_uwsgi.ini
```

I get this error:

```
2016/03/03 12:23:26 [crit] 6232#0: *1 connect() to unix:///home/user/Documents/mysite/mysite.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: 192.168.174.169, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///home/user/Documents/mysite/mysite.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:8000"
```

The strange thing is, I had and still have this exact same setup on a different machine (with the same files), and it works. I copy pasted the files to this new machine and now it gives this error.

So I know these config files have worked before and when I start up my old machine, these files work perfectly with no permission denied error.

How come on my new machine it is giving a permission denied error?

Edit: For what it's worth, I did `groups` in my old machine and this was the output:

```
myUser adm cd-rom sudo dip www-data plugdev lpadmin sambashare
```

and when I did `groups www-data` this was the output:

```
www-data: www-data ayman
```

However, when I did `groups` on my new machine, `www-data` did not exist. Not sure if this has anything to do with the issue.

Answer (score 2):

In points below i will refer to your user and your group. Those are user and group on which uWSGI server runs. Most probably, group will have same name as your username.

1. **Check on what user and group nginx is running**. It can be different group even on same system version. It may depend on the way you've installed nginx server. You can check it in main nginx config.
2. **Don't put your sockets file in user's home directory**. Some of unix systems will prevent other users from accessing them. Good place for socket files is `/run/` or `/var/run/` (for some of systems only one of them exists). If you can't use `/run/` and `/var/run/`, you can also use `/tmp/`.
3. **Add nginx user (from point 1) to your group**. Other way around (adding your user to nginx group) will work too, but sometimes you will have to change socket ownership.
4. **change socket owner to mix nginx user or group with your user or group**. For example `youruser:www-data` or `nginx:yourgroup`. You can do it by adding:

   ```
   chown-socket = youruser:www-data
   ```

   to your uWSGI config.

Fulfilling that points should fix your issue with permissions once forever.

Comment: thanks for this. Quick question though, wouldn't adding the nginx user (which is www-data) to my users group give the nginx user admin permissions? Because my user has admin permissions. Is there another group I can add www-data to so that uwsgi doesn't give me a permission denied error?

Comment: What do you mean by "admin permissions"? All is determined by your permissions in system file. You can limit permissions to source code, so your user group will be able to access and only read files that are needed to run your web application.

Comment: When I run the command `groups` I see `myUser` as one of the groups. You mentioned to add the nginx user (www-data) to my group (I'm using by this you mean my user's group, right?). But when I view the groups which `myUser` is part of by running the command `groups myUser`, it lists `sudo` as one of the groups. Doesn't that mean I'd be giving the Nginx user (www-data) `sudo` permissions, which is basically an admin user?

Comment: If I'm vegetarian and user of stackoverflow (so i am member of this 2 groups), does it make you an vegetarian (because you're member of stackoverflow too)? No :) And if you're confused by group named same as your username, it just an group, there is nothing special about it and giving someone that group won't give him all permissions that you have (unless you will give that group all of your permissions).